# 3 Questions about modern Physics

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, popular-science, spacetime-dimensions, higgs

First, I'd like to apologize for both my writing skills (I'm not English) and for my physics knowledge (being them very basic and/or naive).

- With general relativity from Einstein, gravity is no longer labeled as a force. However, I find it hard to understand what gravity is if it's not a force. I mean, if we ignore the energy of a system and we calculate the gravity field using the newtonian formula, the result would be a force since it's true that "$F=ma$" when we calculate the force with $F=mg$.

But now we know energy also affects gravity so i wonder if it wouldn't be posible to still use newtonian gravity model adapted with Einstein's famous "$E=mc^2$" and so to calculate the gravity field we would use: "$g =    G(m+E/c^2)/r^2$"
And to calculate the force resulting from the interation with the field and another entity (be it mass or energy) we would use: "$F = (m+E/c^2)g$".

- My other grip with modern physics is     string theory. Every other theory untill now could be proven to be true or false sooner or latter, however, string theory is just a mathematical model that requires our universe to have 10 (or 11) dimensions from witch we can only appreciate 3 of them.

Will this theory ever be proven to be true or false? Or will we remain playing by the pseudo-science rules?

- Higgs Boson. Why do we need the hadron colisoner to detect something that's everywhere.... I mean, if mass comes from the interation of the quarks with the higgs boson, then, my body is in contact with the higgs boson.

Comment: Hi Daniel, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! You should ask one question per post. This one I'll leave alone because it already has an answer, but keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Even more, than too broad, the second question is just unconstructive.

Comment: How can a question be constructive/unconstructive? ._. I had doubts and i asked them, that's all...

Comment: @DanielSilva: Because of the remarks of pseudo-science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to stick to the one question "How is gravity not a force" and add to Dimension10's answer in his first paragraph with the following explanation and thought experiment for you to think about.

As in Dimension10's answer, inertial observers are those who both (1) follow geodesics governed by the Einstein field equations and (2) those who, if they carry with them a relatively stationary system of rods to represent their $x, y$ and $z$ axes with many accelerometers mounted along the whole length of each rod, find that **all** of those accelerometers read nought: the jargon, well-googlable phrase which will get you much relevant material is those whose relatively stationary co-ordinate axes are "Lie dragged by the Levi-Civita connexion".

So General Relativity can be thought of as an "application note" for Newton's First Law. You can use the tangent spaces to the manifolds foreordained by the field equations to find out when Newton's First Law holds - that's a rough summary of much of the physical content of GR. Any **deviation** from an inertial frame **must** then come from a force, and the force needed to beget a body's observed acceleration relative to an inertial frame is given by Newton's Second Law $\mathbf{F} = \mathrm{d}_\tau \mathbf{P}$ - here we use force and momentum four vectors and proper time $\tau$ relative to a local inertial frame - this is a technicality that preserves the gist of the idea if you think of the "simple" nonrelativistic Newton II, namely, that only forces can deflect something from a local inertial frame.

So now think about standing or sitting on the Earth and the forces you feel. You feel a squashing on your bottom from your seat if you're sitting or upward impulses jarr your shins if you run along the ground. What would your free body diagram look like? Let's do this firstly as we would in a civil engineering class and then by "using GR as an application note for when to use Newton I".

1. The civil engineer would treat this as a problem in statics where there are **two** forces on you: downwards "weight" exactly balanced by an upwards reaction force on your body from the ground and from your seat; the latter comes from the interaction between the matter of your body and the matter of the seat/ground as the latter stops you from falling through the ground.
2. GR tells us that our locally inertial frames are heading downwards through our feet and through the ground accelerating relative to the Earth's surface at $g$ metres per second squared. So we are indeed **accelerating** upwards relative to these inertial frames at $g$ metres per second squared. So this is actually a problem in **dynamics**! The forces in your free body diagram do **not** balance so as beget this acceleration. We, therefore, apply Newton II to this dynamics problem: there is but **one** force on you, what the civil engineer would call the "reaction" force that arises from the interaction between your body and the matter of the ground and, by Newton II, this force, what you would call your "weight", is $m\,g$ newtons *upwards*. Notice how gravity is no longer a force here. Or rather, it could be thought of as an "inertial" force in the D'Alembertian sense of the word (see the [Wikipedia page on D'Alembert's Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle)).

I know that this is a bit weird at first, but it is ultimately the cleanest and, from the classical (up to and including GR) physics the most real way to think of things. Modern physics to some degree does agree with you, however, in that it seeks to replace the description of classical GR with one wherein gravity is a fundamental force arising from the swap of messenger particles (bosons), in this case, the graviton. The only problem is that we don't yet have a consistent and experimentally proven quantum gravity theorem, so we don't yet really know what a graviton is. To touch on another of your questions, as far as I can tell with my non-string theoretically-kitted understanding, this is why string theory is important as an investigation into what a quantum gravity theory might look like, even if string theory itself is ultimately disproven.

Answer (score 1):

1. You'll often hear that gravity is akin to an "inertial force" in general relativity. This is exactly correct -- gravity is only felt when you actively cling-on to a non-inertial (which means "non-freefalling" in general relativity) reference frame, so you're not moving on a geodesic, which is what your inertia tries to make you do.
2. Is the rest of the question a Trojan horse for this? There is no "pseudo-science" in string theory, the fact that it does makes predictions is brain-dead obvious, regardless of whether those predictions feel nice to you or not. The method theories are chosen in physics is called "[abduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abductive_reasoning)", which is a Bayesian inference technique with experimental data influencing a probability prior that is based on theory complexity. Even if a theory were only a mathematical reformulation of existing knowledge, it could still have value for simplicity (simple in the "low Kolmogorov complexity" sense, not in the "can a squirrel undersand it?" sense). But string theory makes new predictions, so the question is moot.
3. The Higgs boson isn't "everywhere". But even stuff that is everywhere can be expensive to detect, e.g. gravitational waves (in this case because you needed to have high energy ones to be able to detect them easily).

Comment: Predicting non-observed supersymmetry isn't a plus.

Comment: I surely didn't mean to offend any1. It's just that a model that is purely based on nothing else but mathematics doesn't sound plausible for me. And if it can't be proven true or false (you didn't even touch that subject, so i'll continue assuming it can't unless some1 explains how would it be proven true. Like when Einstein postulated general relativity, latter he had to prove it true or wrong with the solar eclipse.) then how can it be real science? Again i'd like to apologize for my little knowledge, all i know about this subjects is from internet research.

Comment: No, he explained to you that it can be proven and almost has been. Thus it is science. EDIT: better be careful, because you really are starting to sound like a troll. Read the answer.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS: it doesn't.  Extra dimensions and supersymmetry are really the only things that makes it a testable theory at all.

Comment: Though I should add that neither are evidence for string theory, just that existence would show string theory to not be definitely wrong.  (not to say that there aren't compelling reasons to believe string theory, that is definitely true)

Comment: You could use a politeness text filter to a person who said he is not expert. But apparently ST does not predict a politeness text filter, what a pity :D

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS: curve fitting is not a prediction.  The Higgs mass is a SUSY prediction, not a string theory prediction.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS: yes, but you can have the MSSM without string theory.   You need Supersymmetry for string theory, but you don't need string theory for supersymmetry.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS: your last statement is certainly true.